# How to insert new records from one table into another table

Tags: sql, ms-access, duplicates, left-join

I want to insert into my `tbl_Cumulative` any new records that appear in `tbl_Daily`. My `tbl_Cumulative` is comprehensive of all historical `tbl_Daily` records. `tbl_Daily` is refreshed every day.

My `INSERT INTO` statement looks like below:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_Cumulative
SELECT *
FROM tbl_Daily
LEFT JOIN tbl_Cumulative
ON tbl_Cumulative.ID= tbl_Daily.ID
WHERE tbl_Cumulative.ID IS NULL
```

I first join the tables based on `ID` and where there is no match with `tbl_Cumulative` (aka a record is new), then append it to `tbl_Cumulative`.
However, I end up getting the below error:

> Duplicate output destination 'ID'.

I know there is duplicate fields for `ID` because `tbl_Cumulative` and `tbl_Daily` have the exact same columns. How could I query my SQL so that I can still match new queries and append them to `tbl_Cumulative`?

Comment: Tell the db engine which fields you want it to consider: `INSERT INTO tbl_Cumulative (<field list>) SELECT <field list>`

Comment: HansUp I was hoping to avoid manually typing each field in as there are much too many to do by hand. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Yes, build your query in the Access query designer.  Then instead of typing the field names, you need only select them in the design grid.

Comment: If that suggestion is not satisfactory, see whether changing `SELECT *` to `SELECT tbl_Daily.*` is sufficient.

Comment: Yes! Using `SELECT tbl_Daily.*` works perfectly! Thanks. If you post that answer I will flag it as correct :)

Comment: Yes, I missed that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT` the fields from only one table (`tbl_Daily.*`) instead of all the fields returned in the `SELECT *` result set.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_Cumulative
SELECT tbl_Daily.*
FROM tbl_Daily
LEFT JOIN tbl_Cumulative
ON tbl_Cumulative.ID= tbl_Daily.ID
WHERE tbl_Cumulative.ID IS NULL
```